# Image blob loading and css filters

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

Is it somehow possible to do something, not on load, but on image render in javascript?

We have a following scenario:

1. Image data is downloaded from a remote server with xhr, and turned into a blob.
2. The blobs url is passed to the image element `image.src = url;`
3. Image has an `onload` listener, which sets a css filter for an image, different for each image.

Sometimes, especially for bigger images, there is a blink of an unfiltered image, and than a properly filtered image is displayed. On the other hand, setting the filter during the `src` assign causes the previously displayed image to flicker for a moment with a wrong filter. This happens in all major browsers.

Any ideas how to make it silky smooth? :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

1. Image data is downloaded from a remote server with xhr, and turned into a blob.
2. Before assigning the `src`, hide the `img` contents, by changing either [`display`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) or [`visibility`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_visibility.asp) attribute.

   ```
   display: none;
   //OR
   visibility: hidden;
   ```
3. The blobs url is passed to the image element `image.src = url;`.

   This would load the `img` content but it would be invisible.
4. Now apply the CSS filters as per your requirement. The `img` would be invisible so there would be no flicker or anything.
5. Now change the `display` or `visibility` attribute back.

   ```
   display: initial;
   //OR
   visibility: visible;
   ```

   Additionally, if you are using JQuery or some other library you can animate the transition using functions such as [`fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/), [`slideDown()`](http://api.jquery.com/slidedown/), so that it all appears super smooth and fancy.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion, but it would flicker with a black/invisible image instead of the unfiltered one. The images have to change instantly, almost like in an animation or a movie - the "gaps" between changes should not be visible.

Comment: Oh, I see, so its like a movie. Well, say you have two function, `applyeffect()` and `display()`. Suppose `applyeffect()` does parts 1-4. And `display()` does 5. Try it such a way that when `display()` is triggered you trigger `applyeffect()` in the background, so that the preprocessing is being done, and you just have to display it. You can use maybe another `img` to store this preemptively loaded image. Then just keep cycling between displaying the two.

Comment: It would still have the same problem - I wouldn't know if the "background" image is in an unfiltered or filtered state to show it. I'm begining to think this is a browser rendering issue, not something I can fix with js :/